# Proximity sensor with wakelock issue: can't turn on screen again

Tags: android, sensors, proximity, wakelock

I've been looking around for the last days and none of the answers to the questions made have helped me and I'm bumping my head with something that perhaps is simple to solve .... I want to work with the proximity sensor and what I'm doing is that if I put the finger on the sensor it turns off the screen and if I remove the finger away it turns back on the screen! I'm sucessfully turning off the screen and I'm getting the  "Log.i("info", "trying to turn on!")" message when I remove the finger but somehow the screen doesn't turn on .... I've tried with wakelock (commented) and with flags with no sucess! If I remove the finger the lights on the keypad turn on but the screen won't .. If I press the power button two times it turns on the screen sucessfully! Can anyone give me an help with it? :(

```
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        if(event.sensor.getType()==Sensor.TYPE_PROXIMITY){
    ProximityReading.setText("\nProximity Sensor Reading:" + String.valueOf(event.values[0]));
    }

        if(event.values[0] == 0) {
      WindowManager.LayoutParams params = getWindow().getAttributes();
      getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
          getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
      getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
      params.screenBrightness = 0f;
      getWindow().setAttributes(params);
            } else {
          WindowManager.LayoutParams params = getWindow().getAttributes();
      params.screenBrightness = 1f;
      getWindow().setAttributes(params);

      /*powermanager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        wakeLock = powermanager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, "TAG");
      wakeLock.acquire();

      Log.i("info", "trying to turn on!");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want turn screen on,you can use the API such as "TurnScreenOn" in PowerManager,or use ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP combined with FULL_WAKE_LOCK

Comment: unfortunately it simply does not work :( turns off the screen but never turns on again .. And I can't find any "TurnScreenOn" in PowerManager :(

Comment: The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#FULL_WAKE_LOCK) says 

`This constant was deprecated in API level 17.
Most applications should use FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON instead of this type of wake lock, as it will be correctly managed by the platform as the user moves between applications and doesn't require a special permission.`

Answer (score 0):

I use the following method to unlock the phone,lighten it up and then reenable the keyguard lock.

```
public void unlockAndPowerup(){
    KeyguardManager km = (KeyguardManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
    final KeyguardManager.KeyguardLock kl = km.newKeyguardLock("MyKeyguardLock");
    kl.disableKeyguard();

    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE); 
    WakeLock wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK
            | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP
            | PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE, "MyWakeLock");

    wakeLock.acquire();
    wakeLock.release();
    kl.reenableKeyguard();
}
```

Comment: This is using a deprecated API as the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#FULL_WAKE_LOCK) says 

`This constant was deprecated in API level 17.
Most applications should use FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON instead of this type of wake lock, as it will be correctly managed by the platform as the user moves between applications and doesn't require a special permission.`

Answer (score 0):

Your procedure is wrong. It may work on some devices by chance, but that's not the way to do it.

1. **FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON** is supposed to be **applied on the onCreate method** of an activity. You need to modify your app logic.
2. Your screen off technique is incorrect. You're modifying brightness, that's a hacky way, and may not turn off screen at all, and drain battery.
   You need to achieve it via Device Admin permission. That's the official way to do it

Locking sample code

```
public static void lockNow(Context c) {
    DevicePolicyManager dpm = (DevicePolicyManager)c.getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
    if(dpm.isAdminActive(new ComponentName(c.getApplicationContext(),DeviceAdmin.class)))
        dpm.lockNow();
}
```

DeviceAdmin.java

```
import android.app.admin.DeviceAdminReceiver;
public class DeviceAdmin extends DeviceAdminReceiver {
}
```

In the manifest

```
<receiver
        android:name=".admin.DeviceAdmin"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.device_admin"
            android:resource="@xml/admin" />

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

And asking for Device Admin permission

```
private void askAdminPerm(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN);
    intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADMIN,
            new ComponentName(root.getContext(), DeviceAdmin.class));
    intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_ADD_EXPLANATION, getString(R.string.lock_msg_big));
    startActivity(intent);
}
```